# Fetch name based on single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Need help with below query which I am not able to figure out
I have two tables

**Table 1 - User**

```
UserId  Name
------  ----
1       Abc
2       Xyz
3       Pqr
4       Ppp
5       AAA
```

**Table 2 - SubscriptionAssignment**

```
UserId  PlanName  PurchasedBy
------  --------  -----------
1       Basic     3
2       Pro       3
4       Pro       5
```

(UserId and PurchasedBy has foreign key reference to UserId in User table). I want to get reporting data by joining these two table in below format where lets say

PurchasedBy=3

```
Name  PlanName  PurchasedBy
----  --------  -----------
Abc   Basic     Pqr
Xyz   Pro       Pqr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do join the two tables, along with a second join back to `User` to bring in the names of the users who did the purchasing.

```
SELECT
    u1.Name,
    sa.PlanName,
    u2.Name AS PurchasedBy
FROM User u1
INNER JOIN SubscriptionAssignment sa
    ON sa.UserId = u1.UserId
INNER JOIN User u2
    ON u2.UserId = sa.PurchasedBy
WHERE
    sa.PurchasedBy = 3;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: @Shiriram - please take a look at this tutorial: https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-multiple-joins-for-beginners-with-examples/ to better understand "why" this answer is correct, and how to solve similar SQL queries yourself.

Comment: @FoggyDay ...which is why I avoid lengthy edits, unless I can't even see the data myself.